# If values in Column A are the same and other values are equal to, then put X in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, case

I have something like this...

| FlightNum | Class | Seats | SoldOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 0 |  |
| 10 | B | 5 |  |
| 10 | C | 15 |  |
| 10 | D | 25 |  |

I want to write a statement where FlightNum is the same, and A class has 0 seats, all rows for that FlightNum should put a "1" in the SoldOut column.

| FlightNum | Class | Seats | SoldOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 10 | B | 5 | 1 |
| 10 | C | 15 | 1 |
| 10 | D | 25 | 1 |

I'm not really sure where to start other than case statements, so I'm looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We check if `Class = 'A' and Seats = 0`  and then we use `count` window function separated by `FlightNum` to give the result to the entire flight.

```
select  *
       ,count(case when Class = 'A' and Seats = 0 then 1 end) over(partition by FlightNum) as SoldOut
from    t
```

| FlightNum | Class | Seats | SoldOut |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 0 | 1 |
| 10 | B | 5 | 1 |
| 10 | C | 15 | 1 |
| 10 | D | 25 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3Lq2G36w)